# How can I setup of logstash.conf in a microservice architecture?

Tags: docker, logstash, kibana, microservices, elastic-stack

I have a microservice based architecture where each microservice is running in a container. I'm in the process of setting up an ELK stack (also in containers). Each microservices' logs end up on the host machine at `/log/<microservice>/*.log`

I'm looking at how to have injest each microservices' logs from that path. What does my logstash.conf need to look like.

A follow up question is that each of my requests have an x-request-id which is in each log message, so if I want to trace a request through the microservices, how can I set up that type of filtering (in logstash?) and view it in Kibana?

Thanks,
Jas

Comment: I would not use Logstash to stream the logs from each container to ES, I'd use Filebeat which is a lightweight data shipper meant exactly for that purpose. Logstash is useful as a centralized log processing solution, but if you only need to stream logs to ES and extract some fields (e.g. `x-request-id`), leveraging [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html) + [ES ingest nodes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) is the way to go.

Comment: So I'm not streaming the logs to logstash, but logstash would just be reading the logs from the host from the `/log/<microservice>` directories. But, perhaps filebeat is still the best option there as well? Can  you go into a little more detail?

Comment: yes, reading logs and streaming them is easier with filebeat than logstash.